# VersionNotFoundError when writing S3 bucket from a Custom Dataset

Tags: kedro, dataset

I have a custom dataset which I am using to write a popmon report to S3 bucket

class ReportDataset(AbstractVersionedDataSet):

```
def __init__(self, filepath: str, version: Version = None, credentials: Dict[str, Any] = None):
    _credentials = deepcopy(credentials) or {}
    protocol, path = get_protocol_and_path(filepath)
    self._protocol = protocol
    self._fs = fsspec.filesystem(self._protocol, **_credentials)
    super().__init__(
        filepath=PurePosixPath(path),
        version=version,
        exists_function=self._fs.exists,
        glob_function=self._fs.glob, )

def _load(self):
    raise DataSetError("Write Only Datatset")

def _save(self, data) -> None:
    """Saves data to the specified filepath."""
    save_path = get_filepath_str(self._get_save_path(), self._protocol)
    save_dir = Path(save_path).parent
    save_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with open(save_path, "w+") as file:
        file.write(data.to_html())
```

And getting below error:-
raise VersionNotFoundError(f"Did not find any versions for {self}")
kedro.io.core.VersionNotFoundError:Did not find any versions for ReportDataset(filepath=,protocol=s3, version=Version(load=None, save='2022-04-20T16.45.05.872Z'))

With the same code I am able to write to local folder location. I am using kedro==0.17.4

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is a popmon report?